# Quartz jobs not running in Azure websites?

Tags: java, azure, quartz-scheduler

I have upgraded Azure website to Basic and basically use it as Amazon beanstalk.  It seems like the Quartz jobs don't run.  There is no Catalina.out file and the one log file mapping to the same date seems to have just a few entries.

```
Jul 28, 2014 4:05:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 28, 2014 4:05:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@287ef1bf')
Jul 28, 2014 4:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 28, 2014 4:06:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 28, 2014 4:06:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
```

Has anyone got Quartz running successfully?  The reason I am using websites is because it's making it easy for me to set up tomcat and SSL.  Maybe I should just rev up a simple linux box?

Comment: I have done it multiple times but using c# on Azure. But I dont thing that matters. Kindly share some code snippet. Also, have you marked the site "Always On" as "On"?

Comment: Did you manage to make this work in the end?